# How to find antilog with simple calculator?

Tags: arithmetic, calculator

I know how to find log to base $10$ using simple calculator:

say if you want to find log of $12$ you can do as blow:

Step 1: $13$ times $\sqrt{\star} \implies 1.00030338$;
Step 2: subtract 1: $1.00030338 - 1 = 0.00030338$;
Step 3: Multiply by $3558 = 1.07942$.

Can I find $\operatorname{antilog}$ too?

---

By simple calculator i mean this:

[image]

Comment: Define "simple calculator".  Compared to mathematica, even a TI-83 is "simple".

Comment: Isn't $\operatorname{antilog}_{10} 12 = 10^{12}$. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @rubik 12 is just an example.

Comment: @Hayden i have edited question.

Comment: Hey @Freddy, can you provide a link where I could check whether that log thing is real, not by just some examples but for all numbers?

Comment: Rather than using these arcane calculations to get $\log_{10}{12}$, it's better to remember that $\log_{10}2 \approx 0.301$ and $\log_{10}3 \approx 0.477$. Then you immediately have $$\log_{10}12 = 2\log_{10}2 + \log_{10}3 \approx 2\cdot0.301+0.477 = 1.079.$$

Comment: As for the other direction, use the fact that $\ln 10 \approx 2.3$ and that near $x=0$, you have $e^x \approx \frac{2+x}{2-x}$. Then, for example, $$10^{1.079} = 10\cdot10^{0.079} \approx 10\frac{2+0.079\cdot2.3}{2-0.079\cdot2.3}=11.9985\ldots,$$ a pretty good approximation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using your calculator's square root key, you can approximate any antilog as closely as you like.  Say you want $10^{1.234}$.  You start by writing $$1.234 \approx  1 + \frac18 + \frac1{16} + \frac1{32} + \frac1{128}$$ which you can find by any of several straightforward methods.  (If this isn't clear, leave a comment and I will explain it further.)

Then you can calculate $$\begin{align}10^{1/8} &= \sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{10}}}\\
10^{1/16} &= \sqrt{10^{1/8}}\\
10^{1/32} &= \sqrt{10^{1/16}}\\
10^{1/128} &= \sqrt{\sqrt{10^{1/32}}} \\
\end{align}$$

and so on.  Then $$10^{1.234} \approx 10\cdot 10^{1/8}\cdot 10^{1/16}\cdot 10^{1/32} \cdot 10^{1/128}.$$

You can be a little more clever than this.  $1.234$ is almost, but not quite, $1 + \frac18 + \frac1{16} + \frac1{32} + \frac1{64}$, so you can get a much better approximationby writing $$1.234\approx 1 + \frac18 + \frac1{16} + \frac1{32} + \frac1{64} \color{red}{- \frac1{512}}$$

and then $$10^{1.234}\approx 10\cdot 10^{1/8}\cdot 10^{1/16}\cdot 10^{1/32}\cdot 10^{1/64}\color{red}{\div 10^{1/512}}.$$

Answer (score 0):

To find the antilog using a simple calculator, you can follow these steps:

1. Take the numbers after the decimal point (if any) from the log result.
2. Divide the result from step 1 by 3558.
3. Add 1 to the result from step 2.
4. Square the result from step 3 thirteen times (multiply by itself).

For example, if you want to find the antilog of 2.345:

Step 1: Numbers after the decimal = 0.345
Step 2: 0.345 / 3558 = 0.00009696459
Step 3: Add 1 => 1.00009696459
Step 4: Square 13 times => 2.218 (approx)

Now, the number before the decimal in the result is used as the power of 10 and multiplied to the answer. In this case, it's 2.218 * 10^2, resulting in a final answer of approximately 221.8.

Feel free to use the whole number if there is one, but note that the answer may vary.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

Just do the reverse of what u did. Like if u want to find antilog of 2.345
Step-1 Take numbers after decimal : 0.345
Step-2 Divide it by 3558: 0.00009696459
Step-3 Add 1: 1.00009696459
Step-4 Square it 13 times: Press * and = 13 times: 2.218 (approx)
Step 5- Now the number before decimal is used as power of 10 and multiplied to the answer: 2.218 *10^2
Final answer= 221.8 
(You may also take the whole number -2.345 and use it in the method. But answer may vary!)

Comment: Please use MathJax to format your answer. Here is a great guide: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference.