# Algebra: How do I solve unusual exponents without using a calculator?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I worked from $\log(492x)=5.728$ using tables and got $x=10^{3.036}$. Is there any way to get the answer of 1086.5129 without using a calculator that has an exponent key?

Along the same lines, can the natural logarithm $e^{-1.524}$ be solved by converting to base 10 log tables or any other way without using a calculator that has an exponent key?

Comment: The usual way to calculate using tables (known to all physical scientists and engineers before 1960 or so) involved two tables: logarithm and antilogarithm.

Comment: No, but $e^{-1.524}\approx 0.999^{1524}$ to 3 digits which can be computed by squaring and multiplying in $<20$ multiplications.

Comment: @GEdgar Before 1960, sure. Also before 1980, I would think.

Comment: Note that if you have a table of logs you can work it backward to perform exponentiation, although it's less convenient than the usual use of the table.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find antilog with simple calculator?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1137918/how-to-find-antilog-with-simple-calculator)  (“Simple calculator” is one that has a square root key, but no exponent function.)

Comment: For the value of $e^{-1.524}$ one might try a few terms of the series expansion.

Comment: Antilogs aren't even addressed in the algebra book I'm working out of, but I did find them addressed in a different algebra book, altho only briefly.  But I see they are calculated using the mantissa and characteristic of a log, which I know something about, so I shall have to study up on this and see how I fare.  I sincerely thank everyone for their kind comments and getting me started on my way again.  (Just for today's laugh, I'm a 67 y/o who is struggling thru algebra books I bought at the Goodwill just because I remembered enjoying algebra in college (way back when)).

Comment: The “antilog” of $x$ is just another name for $10^x$, nothing more.  You said you wanted to know how to calculate $10^{3.036}$ and that post says how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

For the question

> Along the same lines, can the natural logarithm $e^{−1.524}$ be solved by converting to base 10 log tables or any other way without using a calculator that has an exponent key?

Notice that $\,e^x = 10^{x\log e}\,$ and
$\,\log e \approx .43429.\,$

Finding $\,10^x\,$ is done using a log table to find antilogs.

For the question about solving $\,\log(492x)=5.728\,$

> without using a calculator that has an exponent key

The solution is $\,x = 10^{5.728}/492 = 10^5 10^{.728}/492.$

Compute $10^{.728} = e^{.728/\log e}$ to $5$ digit precision with

$\,\log(2) \approx .30103\,$ and $\,\log e \approx .43429.\,$

Let $\,t := (.728+.30103-1)/.43429 \approx .06684\,$ and

use the approximation (when $\,t\,$ is small) of
$\,e^t\approx 1+t\,$ to get

$\,x = 10^6(1+.06684)/(492\times 2) \approx 1084.2\,.$

Use a more accurate approximation $\,e^t\approx 1+t+t^2/2\,$ to get

$\,x = 10^6(1+.06684+.06684^2/2)/(492\times 2) \approx 1086.46\,.$